# How to change the margin of an "included" layout programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layoutparams, android-include

I have a LinearLayout inside which I am including a different layout. Something like this

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:visibility="visible">

                    <include
                        layout="@layout/new_layout"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now what I would like to do is, to programmatically change the "marginBottom" of the included layout (new_layout). How can I do that?

I tried calling various LayoutParams and tried changing the margin, but not sure if it is the right approach. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. Make the Linear layout using your id

```
    LinearLayout ll =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 20);

    layoutParams.setMargins(left,top,right,bottom);
```

where you can pass the value in setMargins

and if you want to input value in dp.. Try this

```
public void setMargin(Context con,ViewGroup.LayoutParams params,int dp) {

    final float scale = con.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    // convert the DP into pixel
    int pixel =  (int)(dp * scale + 0.5f); 

    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams s =(ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)params;
    s.setMargins(pixel,pixel,pixel,pixel);

    yourView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

where you can pass your layout params

Answer (score 0):

include.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:id="@+id/include_layout">

<ImageView android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cross" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<include layout="@layout/include"/>

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:padding="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    LinearLayout included=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.include_layout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.setMargins(Math.round(10), Math.round(10), Math.round(10), Math.round(10));

    //set margin...
    included.setLayoutParams(params);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly change or modify margins in the `<include>` tag. This tag is just adding the layout resource in the current view hierarchy without adding an extra parent view container.

So essentially what you want to do is set margins on the root view container of the "included layout". That is you should directly call `findViewById()` for the root view and set all of your margins on it pro grammatically and as the included view's parent is a `Linear-layout` you should use

```
   LinerLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinerLayout.LayoutParams) includedRootView.getLayoutParams();
   params.setMargins();
   includedViewRoot.setLayoutParams(params);`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by dimensions also

```
res/values/dimens.xml    
res/values-small/dimens.xml    
res/values-normal/dimens.xml    
res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think this code helpful...

**include.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/include_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
     layout="@layout/include" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.stackdemo;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 LinearLayout include_layout;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    include_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.include_layout);

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 100);
    include_layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
 }

  }
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, although one small difference that I have in my code is 'include.xml' is a RelativeLayout. And when I try to get LayoutParams with RelativeLayout, it gives me ClassCastException. So I switched it to LinearLayout and it crashes with Cannot cast ViewGroup to LinearLayout. All sorts of weird errors :/